# how to get access to controller scope when testing directive with isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, scope, controller, angularjs-scope

I have directive with isolate scope and controller, Is it right to write unit tests for directive and test some functional in controller scope?

And if it right, how i can get access to controller scope?

```
   angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirecive', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            scope: {
                data: '='
            },

            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.f= function () {
                    $scope.value = true;
                };
            },

            link: function ($scope) {
              // some logic
            });
            }
        };
    })

    describe('myDirective', function () {
        'use strict';

        var element,
            $compile,
            $rootScope,
            $scope;

        beforeEach(module('myApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            element = compileElement();
        }));

        function compileElement() {
            var element = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>');
            var compiledElement = $compile(element)($scope);

            $scope.$digest();

            return compiledElement;
        }

        it('should execute f', function () {
            $scope.f();
            expect($scope.val).toBe(true); // there we can access to isolate scope from directive;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller is given the isolated scope created by the directive. Your `$scope`, that you pass into compile function, is used as a parent for the directive's isolate scope.

Answering how to test it, you have two options:

1. Access the isolated scope from the element:

   `var isolated = element.isolateScope();`

   For that, you need to have `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);`
2. Access the isolated scope from your scope:

   `var isolated = $scope.childHead;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
describe('myDirective', function () {
    'use strict';

    var element,
        dirCtrlScp,
        $compile,
        $rootScope,
        $scope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        element = compileElement();
    }));

    function compileElement() {
        var element = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>');
        var compiledElement = $compile(element)($scope);
        dirCtrlScp = element.controller;
        $scope.$digest();

        return compiledElement;
    }

    it('should execute f', function () {
        dirCtrlScp.f();
        expect(dirCtrlScp.value).toBe(true); // there we can access to isolate scope from directive;
    });
});
```

> Have a look at this [Article](http://daginge.com/technology/2014/03/03/testing-angular-directive-controllers-with-jasmine-and-karma/)